# How to setup nginx multiple apps and mutiple ports with one ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have already deployed in HTTPS. This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 3000 ssl;
  listen [::]:3000 ssl;

  server_name localhost hostname.com;
  ssl_certificate      ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  privatekey.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

      location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
      }
}
```

I want to run new app with new port on the same domain, I try to add this:

```
server {
  listen 4000 ssl;
  listen [::]:4000 ssl;

  server_name localhost hostname.com;
  ssl_certificate      ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  privatekey.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

      location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
      }
}
```

When run two app I can use https only port 3000 but can not use app on port 4000. How to config file?

Comment: I cannot see any real problem with the configuration you show. Please check your log files (specifically the error logs) for anything. Also what exactly does *"... can not use app on port 4000 ..."* really mean, i.e. what is the app doing with this port, is it actually trying to use this port and is it using this port with https at all? And, is the server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` even running?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is running in server and can open `hostname.com:4000` only in the server but when I use my browser why can not access this site or this problem is about the network??

Comment: *"... can open hostname.com:4000 only in the server ..."* - which suggests that this is not a problem of nginx. It is likely more a problem of a firewall settings, i.e. something is blocking access to port 4000 on this system from your __remote__ machine. Given that I have no idea of your network setup and what firewalls  or other security measures are done at what places I cannot suggest though where you need to look next - but again, it is likely not nginx.

Comment: Note though that is probably not the best idea to have a local server on port __4000__ accessible on port 3000 and the a local server on port 8000 accessible on port __4000__ remotely. This use of the same port for different things might actually cause trouble too. Again, look at the server error logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check firewall settings and the server error logs